# Error: Could not find 'nx' module in this workspace

Tags: compiler-errors, ivy, nrwl-nx, nrwl

In trying to *build* an app I am getting the following error:
Compiling with Angular sources in Ivy partial compilation mode. Could not find 'nx' module in this workspace. TypeError: (intermediate value)(intermediate value)(intermediate value).split is not a function

I am using nx 16.10.0.

I can't locate any information on this. Can somebody tell me how to fix this error.

Thank you, Al

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error message is super misleading.  My real issue was a misconfigured library.  The stack trace that you're getting is likely for an error *thrown during error processing*, not the stack trace for the *original error*, which is what is causing the problem.

You'll see that the first frame of the stack trace is the file `/node_modules/nx/src/utils/params.js:17` (exact path may vary slightly depending on your package manager).  Open this file and add a console log of the whole `err.message` object before line 17.  In my case, this revealed the **real** error that NX was choking on:

```json
{
  category: 3,
  code: 0,
  messageText: 'Unable to import symbol ClickOutsideDirective.',
  next: [
    {
      category: 3,
      code: 0,
      messageText: "The file <projectRoot>/libs/shared/ui-click-outside-directive/src/lib/click-outside.directive.ts is outside of the configured 'rootDir'.",
      next: undefined
    }
  ]
}
```

That should give you a good place to start investigating where your misconfiguration is.  In my case, the library name in the library's `package.json` file didn't match the library name in my `tsconfig.base.json` file.  Updating the name in the library's `package.json` file fixed the problem.  Hopefully NX will fix this issue with their error logging at some point.

Comment: Thanks Evan! Didn't see this answer until after I was forced to recreate the app and run Angular and nx v17 which eliminated the problem.